# Handling JavaScript objects in a C++ node nan addon

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, v8, node-nan

My code is passing a JavaScript object to a function implemented in C++. The C++ code needs to validate the type of each property and supply a default value if either the property is missing or the type is wrong.

The following code seems to work (only showing the integer case) but I'm wondering if there is a more straightforward way to handle this. I'm by no means an expert in this area so all suggestions for improvements are welcome.

```
int get_integer(
    v8::Local<v8::Object> obj,
    v8::Local<v8::String> prop,
    int default_value = 0) {

    if (Nan::Has(obj, prop).FromMaybe(false)) {
        Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v = Nan::Get(obj, prop);
        if (!v.IsEmpty()) {
            v8::Local<v8::Value> val = v.ToLocalChecked();
            if (val->IsInt32() || val->IsNumber()) {
                return val->IntegerValue();
            }
        }
    }
    return default_value;
}
```

It's called by code similar to the following:

```
v8::Local<v8::Object> obj = info[0]->ToObject();
v8::Local<v8::String> prop = Nan::New<v8::String>("prop").ToLocalChecked();
int x = get_integer(obj, prop);
```

Answer (score 3):

If what you are looking for is a simplification, you should have a look at the new API called [N-API](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api), supported by NodeJs.

The code becomes lighter as you never have to touch any v8 object directly. The official [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html) is mainly for C, but I recommend that you look into the C++ wrapping. The documentation is not complete, but since you have already used NaN, it is quite similar and you can find some articles on it as well as [the examples](https://github.com/nodejs/abi-stable-node-addon-examples), under the "node-addon-api" folders for the C++ versions.

A [conversion tool](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/blob/master/doc/conversion-tool.md) exists to convert NaN based code to an N-API one, but since you heavily use v8 constructs I recommend that you redo these parts using only the APIs.

Comment: I've taken a look at N-API but need to support code across node version 6, 8, and 10. I understand it will be ported to 6 but until that time N-API is, unfortunately, not an option. I appreciate your suggestion and just wish it could work for me now - thanks.